# ORA-22813 error with SQL complex query

Tags: sql

I have a big `SELECT` statement which has many nested selects in it. When I run it, it gives me an `ORA-22813` error:

> Ora-22813:- The Collection value from one of the inner sub queries has exceeded the system limits and hence this error.

I have given below some of the nested `select`s which return huge data.

---The 1st `select` returns the most data.

Can I handle and process the huge data returned by the `INNER SELECT`s into the tables in any alternate way so that there is no error of memory less, sort size less.
get, any other way so that the QUERY successfully processes without error.

```
/*****************************************BEGIN

LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (  SELECT *

        FROM STUDENT_COURSE stu_c 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_history ch on stu_c.course_id = ch.ch_course_id 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN STUDENT_master stu_mca on ch.course_history_id = stu_mca.item_id

      ) stu_c ON stu_c.HISTORY_ID = toa.ACTIVITY_ID               ----->This table is joined earlier

LEFT OUTER JOIN

    (SELECT c_e.EV_ID, c_e.EV_NAME, ma.item_id, ma.cata_id
FROM EVENTS c_e LEFT OUTER  
JOIN COURSE_master ma on c_e.event_Id = ma.item_id ) c_e ON c_e.EVENT_ID = toa.ACTIVITY_ID
```

After these selects---we have `GROUP_BY`s to further sort.

---I have checked that if I put a extra limit qualification
like `where rownum <30,<20` in each of these `SELECT`s it works fine.

---

Full query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
mcat.CATALOG_ITEM_ID,
mcat.CATALOG_ITEM_NAME ,
mcat.DESCRIPTION,
mcat.CATALOG_ITEM_TYPE,
mcat.DELIVERY_METHOD,
XMLElement("TRAINING_PLAN",XMLAttributes( TP.TPLAN_ID as "id" ),
XMLELEMENT("COMPLETE_QUANTITY", TP.COMPLETE_QUANTITY),
XMLELEMENT("COMPLETE_UNIT", TP.COMPLETE_UNIT),
XMLElement("TOTAL_CREDITS", TP.numberOfCredits ),
XMLELEMENT("IS_CREDIT_BASED", TP.IS_CREDIT_BASED),
XMLELEMENT("IS_FOR_CERT", TP.IS_FOR_CERT),
XMLELEMENT("ACCREDIT_ORG_NAME", TP.ACCRED_ORG_NAME),
XMLELEMENT("ACCREDIT_ORG_ID", TP.accredit_org_id ),
XMLElement("OBJECTIVE_LIST", TP.OBJECTIVE_LIST )
).extract('/').getClobVal() AS PLAN_LIST

FROM 
student_master_catalog mcat 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT stu_tp.TPLAN_ID, 
stu_tp.COMPLETE_QUANTITY, 
stu_tp.COMPLETE_UNIT, 
stu_tp.TPLAN_XML_DATA.extract('//numberOfCredits/text()').getStringVal() as numberOfCredits,
stu_tp.IS_CREDIT_BASED, 
stu_tp.IS_FOR_CERT, 
stu_oa.ACCRED_ORG_NAME, 
stu_tp.TPLAN_XML_DATA.extract('//accreditingOrg/text()').getStringVal() as accredit_org_id,


objective_list.OBJECTIVE_LIST
FROM 
student_training_catalog stu_tp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
stu_accrediting_org stu_oa on stu_tp.TPLAN_XML_DATA.extract('//accreditingOrg/text()').getStringVal() = stu_oa.ACCRED_ORG_ID
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT 
stu_tpo.TPLAN_ID AS OBJECTIVE_TPLAN_ID, 
XMLAgg(
XMLElement("OBJECTIVE",
XMLElement("OBJECTIVE_ID",stu_tpo.T_OBJECTIVE_ID ),
XMLElement("OBJECTIVE_NAME",stu_to.T_OBJECTIVE_NAME ),
XMLElement("OBJECTIVE_REQUIRED_CREDITS_OR_ACTIVITIES",stu_tpo.REQUIRED_CREDITS ),
XMLElement("ITEM_ORDER", stu_tpo.ITEM_ORDER ),
XMLElement("ACTIVITY_LIST", activity_list.ACTIVITY_LIST )
)
) as OBJECTIVE_LIST 
FROM 
stu_TP_OBJECTIVE stu_tpo
INNER JOIN 
stu_TRAINING_OBJECTIVE stu_to ON stu_tpo.T_OBJECTIVE_ID = stu_to.T_OBJECTIVE_ID
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT stu_toa.T_OBJECTIVE_ID AS ACTIVITY_TOBJ_ID, XMLAgg(
XMLElement("ACTIVITY",
XMLElement("ACTIVITY_ID",stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID ),
XMLElement("CATALOG_ID",COALESCE(stu_c.CATALOG_ID, COALESCE( stu_e.CATALOG_ID, stu_t.CATALOG_ID ) ) ),
XMLElement("CATALOG_ITEM_ID",COALESCE(stu_c.CATALOG_ITEM_ID, COALESCE( stu_e.CATALOG_ITEM_ID, stu_t.CATALOG_ITEM_ID ) ) ),
XMLElement("DELIVERY_METHOD",COALESCE(stu_c.DELIVERY_METHOD, COALESCE( stu_e.DELIVERY_METHOD, stu_t.DELIVERY_METHOD ) ) ),
XMLElement("ACTIVITY_NAME",COALESCE(stu_c.COURSE_NAME, COALESCE( stu_e.EVENT_NAME, stu_t.TEST_NAME ) ) ),
XMLElement("ACTIVITY_TYPE",initcap( stu_toa.ACTIVITY_TYPE ) ),
XMLElement("IS_REQUIRED",stu_toa.IS_REQUIRED ),
XMLElement("IS_PREFERRED",stu_toa.IS_PREFERRED ),
XMLElement("NUMBER_OF_CREDITS",stu_lac.CREDIT_HOURS),
XMLElement("ITEM_ORDER", stu_toa.ITEM_ORDER )
)) as ACTIVITY_LIST 
FROM stu_TRAIN_OBJ_ACTIVITY stu_toa
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT distinct lac.LEARNING_ACTIVITY_ID, lac.CREDIT_HOURS


FROM student_training_catalog tp
INNER JOIN stu_TP_OBJECTIVE tpo on tp.TPLAN_ID = tpo.TPLAN_ID
INNER JOIN stu_TRAIN_OBJ_ACTIVITY toa on tpo.T_OBJECTIVE_ID = toa.T_OBJECTIVE_ID
INNER JOIN stu_LEARNINGACTIVITY_CREDITS lac on lac.LEARNING_ACTIVITY_ID = toa.ACTIVITY_ID and tp.TPLAN_XML_DATA.extract ('//accreditingOrg/text()').getStringVal() = lac.ACC_ORG_ID
where tp.tplan_id ='*************'
) stu_lac ON stu_lac.LEARNING_ACTIVITY_ID = stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID ------>This Select returns correct no. of rows
```

I want to join the below nested `SELECT`s with `stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID`. This would solve my issues.

This below `SELECT` inside the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the Problem. it returns too much because 3 tables are joined directly without any value qualification.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( SELECT ch.COURSE_HISTORY_ID, stu_c.COURSE_NAME, mca.catalog_item_id, mca.catalog_id, mca.delivery_method 
FROM stu_COURSE stu_c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN stu_course_history ch on stu_c.course_id = ch.ch_course_id -
--If I can qualify here with ch.ch_course_id = stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID (stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID from the above select with correct no. of rows )
--Here, I get errors because I can't access outside values inside a left outer join

LEFT OUTER JOIN student_master_catalog mca on ch.course_history_id = mca.catalog_item_id
) stu_c ON stu_c.COURSE_HISTORY_ID = stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT stu_e.EVENT_ID, stu_e.EVENT_NAME, mca.catalog_item_id, mca.catalog_id, mca.delivery_method FROM stu_EVENTS stu_e LEFT OUTER JOIN student_master_catalog mca on stu_e.event_Id = mca.catalog_item_id ) stu_e ON stu_e.EVENT_ID = stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT stu_t.TEST_HISTORY_ID, stu_t.TEST_NAME, mca.catalog_item_id, mca.catalog_id, mca.delivery_method FROM stu_TEST_HISTORY stu_t LEFT OUTER JOIN student_master_catalog mca on stu_t.test_history_id = mca.catalog_item_id) stu_t ON stu_t.test_history_id = stu_toa.ACTIVITY_ID
GROUP BY stu_toa.T_OBJECTIVE_ID) ) activity_list ON activity_list.ACTIVITY_TOBJ_ID = stu_tpo.T_OBJECTIVE_ID 
GROUP BY stu_tpo.TPLAN_ID) ) objective_list ON objective_list.OBJECTIVE_TPLAN_ID = stu_tp.TPLAN_ID
)TP ON TP.TPLAN_ID = mcat.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
WHERE 
mcat.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = '*****************' and mcat.CATALOG_ORG_ID = '********')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please post the DDLs, approximate sizes (relative to each other), and the complete query, rather than just an excerpt.

Some quick hits that may or may not solve your problem (for better help, I need better information) --

- Are you sure you mean OUTER join?  Outer joining students to courses means students who are not taking any courses will still be around. Is that the desired behaviour?
- Don't `select *` if you only want a limited subset of the columns.  Enumerate the exact columns you need.  The rest might not seem like much on a row-by-row basis, but when you multiply by the total number of rows you have, this sort of thing can mean the difference between in-memory sorts and spilling to disk.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows of data are you looking at?  there are times when separate queries with programmatic aggregation can work better.  Someone with more knowledge of Oracle query optimization may be able to help, also, tweaking the settings could help here too...

I've had instances where a sproc was being called that aggregated data from more than one source took exponentially longer than two calls in the app, and putting it together in memory.

Comment: The no of rows resturned varies from 1000-20000+.

Anyway we can handle the data without error?

Answer (score 0):

Post DDL of your tables and exact plan of the query.

Meanwhile, try increasing `pga_aggregate_target`, `sort_area_size` and `hash_area_size`